# sql query through jQuery didn't work in Yii2 but work well in native

Tags: php, jquery

I have Yii2 application, and I have a table like this in my database:
[image]

And I'm trying to execute sqlQuery through jquery.
I've set view and jQuery in **index.php**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function showUser(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select a person:</option>
            <option value="1">Alfredo Jangkirik</option>
            <option value="2">Budi Wunduk</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
```

and set the query and database connection in **getuser.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table, td, th {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        th {text-align: left;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'waskita');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con, "ajax_demo");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '" . $q . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
</body>
```

**but It didn't work, How the way to make it work and why it didn't work?**
I need to get value from Sql through jQuery. I've tried this in native project(not using yii2 framework) and it work well.

Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you type the url ".../getuser.php?q=1" on an web browser?

Comment: In yii2? I got "Not Found". I've not set any action in controller for that page.

Comment: I am not an expert in php but it looks like you need to set up the controller action so that the url can be viewed in the browser.

Comment: Me too :D, but I don't need getuser.php viewed in browser, I just need the script inside the getuser.php execute.

Comment: If you comment out the php part in the file can you view it in a browser? Viewing it in a browser is to test whether http get request can reach the url (.../getuser.php?q=1).

Comment: I've tried and it also didn't work my friend. I also tried to set an action, it work but it render the page to another one :( what I need is just like ajax, it only refresh contain, not page.